# Probability for rolling an odd number and tossing a coin on heads - Why they are independent events?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Rolling a dice; if we get numbers 1-4 we throw a coin once, if we get number 6-5 we throw a coin twice.
what's the probability to get zero heads on coin?

Solution: By using the completeness total law

Pr[0 head] = Pr[0 heads | 1-4 on dice] * Pr[rolled 1-4 dice] + Pr[0 heads | 6-5 on dice] *
Pr[rolled 5-6 dice]

= $\frac{1}{2} \frac{4}{6} + (\frac{1}{2})^2 \frac{2}{6} $

I noticed that the events of getting 0 heads and 1-4 on dice are independent (by using the formula), same for 6-5 on dice.
I know we can check independency by the formula, by my question is how to figure it out by heart?

For example; how getting 0 heads is not independent if we get 1-4 rolled dice or 6-5 dice? because if we get 6-5 rolled dice there is a lower chance to get 0 heads since we throw the coin 2 times compared to throw the coin 1 time if we rolled 1-4 which means there's a bigger chance to get 0 heads with 1-4 rolled dice.

Comment: We have no reason to assume that the results of the coin-tossing influence the probability for the results of the dice rolling or vice versa.

Comment: Any chance that you accidentally mixed it up? What you probably meant is that you throw the coin twice if the coin shows 1-4 and not the other way around.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Getting no Heads is *not* independent of the dice throw.  It's a lot more likely that you throw no Heads on a low dice roll than on a high one.  What did you mean?